# What happens when you exceed the File Storage limit?

Tags: file-storage

I've just noticed that our org (Salesforce Unlimited Edition) is 122% of the file storage limit. Specifically, we're using 1.1TB out of a limit of 899.5GB.

I understand we need to reduce this by removing old/irrelevant attachments as an example, but:

- How is this possible that we're so far over?
- What effects might this have on our org?
- How come Salesforce hasn't thrown any "file limit exceeded" as it does with data?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your Salesforce Edition.

Comment: @Himanshu We're on the Unlimited edition, updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the explanation from the [Salesforce document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_storage.htm)

> For file storage, Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise,
>   Performance, and Unlimited Editions are allocated a per-user limit
>   multiplied by the number of users in the organization plus an
>   additional per-organization allocation. For example, a Professional
>   Edition organization with 10 users receives 11 GB of file storage, or
>   100 MB per user multiplied by 10 users plus an additional 10 GB. A
>   Professional Edition organization with 100 users receives 20 GB of
>   file storage, or 100 MB per user multiplied by 100 users plus an
>   additional 10 GB.

File storage and data storage are calculated asynchronously, so your organization’s storage usage isn’t updated immediately if you import or add a large number of records or files.

Comment: Also, the system has a grace area above 100%, somewhere between 125-150% for most orgs. Eventually, it will block further uploads.