# what happens when you reach your data storage limit in an org?

Tags: data

A co-worked told me that the field tracking history wasn't updating for a record. I verified this myself and that is the case. The only thing I can think of is this.

[image]

This is a production org.

Comment: For what it's worth, for a bit more information albeit related to File Storage, I asked as similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102790/what-happens-when-you-exceed-the-file-storage-limit).

Comment: low data limits are silly. what are they using to store your data? PS2 memory cards?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> what happens when I reach my data limit in org?

Strictly speaking, nothing typically happens at 100% storage usage, except that Salesforce starts to notify administrators daily by email about storage usage. Salesforce has a bit of a grace area before you start running into actual errors. I'm not saying you should ignore the problem, because it will eventually get to a point where users will be prohibited from creating or editing records, but you're not (quite) there yet, at least you shouldn't be for a production org.

You can read more about it under [Data storage amount limit exceeded](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213997&type=1):

> If your Organization's active production instance shows as nearing,
>   almost over, or at 100% of it's *(sic)* available storage, it will continue to
>   run as expected without any affect on your applications. At some
>   point, beyond 100%, performance will be degraded. The exact point at
>   which degradation will occur depends on the specifics of your
>   implementation and cannot be predicted exactly. For this reason, it is
>   recommended that you do not exceed available storage limits.

It's not documented exactly what will happen, because salesforce.com wants to encourage customers to be responsible about their data use, but being a mere 2% over the limit shouldn't have an affect on Field History. To be sure, contact Support, and they might be able to give you more information.

Comment: The link you provided is broken for me.

Comment: @TylerZika Looks like I didn't copy it correctly. Try it now.